# Will restoring system image delete other partitions?

Tags: windows-7, restore, desktop-computer, system-restore

Earlier this year I created a system recovery image for C partition.My HDD is 1TB and divided into 4 partitions.

I want to restore my C:\ using that image. Will the restore process delete the 3 other partitions or their contents knowing that I am restoring to the same HDD?

Comment: What have you used to create the recovery image? Ghost? or Windows System Recovery utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used Acronis or a similar third party tool to create a recovery image, you will be clearly asked to specify the partition where you want to restore the image. The image will be restored only to a partition selected, leaving the other partitions with all their files intact.

If the third party tool you used doesn't prompt for a destination partition, be cautious and check their documentation first.

If you used Windows System Restore, it will not affect your files, as it "affects Windows system files, programs, and registry settings. It can also make changes to scripts, batch files, and other types of executable files created under any user account on your computer. System Restore **does not affect personal files, such as e-mail, documents, or photos, so it cannot help you restore a deleted file**. If you have backups of your files, you can restore the files from a backup."

Source:

[System Restore: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/system-restore-faq#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: I want to use System Image NOT system restore to a specific point.... it's an Image created in windows 7>>>>> Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows 7 File Recovery

Comment: It depends on what you have in the image. "A system image recovery **will format everything on each hard drive that was included in a system image**" http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/675-system-image-recovery.html